# How to execute docker commands after a process has started

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices, consul

I wrote a Dockerfile for a service (I have a CMD pointing to a script that starts the process) but I cannot run any other commands after the process has started? I tried using '&' to run the process in the background so that the other commands would run after the process has started but it's not working? Any idea on how to achieve this?

For example, consider I started a database server and wanted to run some scripts only after the database process has started, how do I do that?

**Edit 1:**

My specific use case is I am running a Rabbitmq server as a service and I want to create a new user, make him administrator and delete the default guest user once the service starts in a container. I can do it manually by logging into the docker container but I wanted to automate it by appending these to the shell script that starts the rabbitmq service but that's not working.

Any help is appreciated!

Regards

Comment: If you want to run a database server, I would recommend you to run it as a separate container.

Comment: If you want to run another process along the first one, the `&` should work. I used to write a script that was using `cat` and `grep` on mysql logs, looking for "started successfully" once i needed a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Did you try `RUN` ?

Comment: I didn't specifically mean a database server but gave it as an example. RUN  can be used to run while creating a docker image but I want my command to run only after the container & service start as my command requires the service to be up and running. One way I know is to use & and run it as a background process in the shell script but that didn't work, don't know why. is there any other way?

Comment: Updated the post with the problem I face with Rabbitmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically around your problem with Rabbit MQ - you can create a `rabbitmq.config`  file and copy that over when creating the docker image.

In that file you can specify both a `default_user` and `default_pass` that will be created when an the database is set from scratch see https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

AS for the general problem - you can change the entry point to a script that runs whatever you need and the service you want instead of the run script of the service

Comment: Thanks! I think that's a good idea, I'll implement that for the Rabbit MQ.

Answer (score 0):

I partially understood your question. Based on what I perceived from your question, I would recommend you to mention the Copy command to copy the script you want to run into the dockerfile. Once you build an image and run the container, start the db service. Then exec the container and get into the container, run the script manually.

If you have **CMD** command in the dockerfile, then it will be overwritten by the command you specify during the execution. So, I don't think you have any other option to run the script unless you don't have CMD in the dockerfile.